# Ambigous column in Teradata

Tags: sql-server, teradata

I have one table and one of the columns has 1 to many relation . here is the example

```
table name service

table column name service name, service ID, Service date, severity,service cost
```

now i am trying to pull all then there are multiple entries  based on severity so i do this

```
select b.service_name,a.service_ID,a.Service_dt,Service_cost 
from dbo.table1 a
inner join
(select distinct Service_n,Service_ID from table1 c) b
on a.service_id=b.service_id
```

here if you observe i am trying to take the `service name` from the sub query and  not from main table to avoid getting multiple entries had i chosen the same with severity.I get an error msg ambigous column `Service_name`.

Comment: I created a table with the those fields, ant your query worked with me without any errors (Except for the Service_n, which I changed to service_name)

Comment: The lesson you should be learning here is to ALWAYS specify which table a column comes from. This means every column in your main query and every column in your subquery. It saves so much headache in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on your subquery select column.

```
service_name
```

instead of

```
service_n
```

You can try this.

```
SELECT b.service_name, 
       a.service_id, 
       a.service_dt, 
       service_cost 
FROM   dbo.table1 a 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT service_name, 
                                   service_id 
                   FROM   table1 c) b 
               ON a.service_id = b.service_id
```

Comment: Sir i tried still it gives me  ambiguous column name

Comment: @RajivSrinivasanR You're welcome,You could mark the answer if it help you :)